# Why we need wires?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics, electromagnetic-induction, conductors

Imagine a cell(battery) bent in such a way that the two terminals face each other with some vaccuum in between...i hv confusion in basics..so pardon me...my question is why cant charge flow from one terminal 2 another because columbic force doesnt need medium to propagate.why do we need wires at all.

Comment: Those electrons in the wires are quite happy to remain there. Now, you make the cathode nice and toasty hot, and you will get electron emission and a current flowing under suitable conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Air is an insulator and a *dielectric* (which means it can "conduct" electric fields). Now, it is possible to model the terminals of a battery and the air space between them as a capacitor (which can conduct *brief pulses* of electrical current) but the value of that capacitor will be extremely tiny and so the pulses of electricity it can conduct will be too small to measure. This makes it completely impractical to  use *dielectric coupling* as a way of conducting electrical power without wires.

Note also that dielectric coupling only works for voltages which are changing continuously over time (AC power). The dielectric between the capacitor terminals is an extremely good insulator for *DC power* unless the DC voltage is of order ~tens of thousands of volts.

So... the answer is "No".

Comment: I m talking of vaccuum in between....sir

Answer (score 1):

One way to think about it is that the relative permittivity term in the Coulomb expression is too large for a vacuum, whereas it is smaller for conducting materials.

Comment: Can u eloberate sir?